# Is it possible to limit ng-grids enabled Cell Selection to one column?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Is it possible to limit the editable modus of ng-grids cells to cells in one column only?
I currently use **enableCellEditOnFocus: true** and this *globally allows all cells to be editable*. I do have a specific editableCellTemplate for one column, by *I would like to have **all other columns "readonly"***. 
Any suggestions for a beginner making his first baby-steps with angularjs and ng-grid?

This is the relevant setup of the grid currently:

```
        var app = angular.module('myCoolGridApp', ['ngGrid']);
        app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

            $scope.gridOptions = {
                data: 'myData',
                enableCellSelection: true,
                enableRowSelection: false,
                enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
                jqueryUITheme: true,
                columnDefs: 'colDefs'
            };

            var myCellEditableTemplate = "<input ng-class=\"'colt' + col.index\" ng-input=\"COL_FIELD\" ng-model=\"COL_FIELD\" ng-blur=\"updateEntity(col, row)\"/>";

            $scope.colDefs = [
                    {field: 'group'},
                    {field: 'user'},
                    {field: 'id', displayName: 'ID', editableCellTemplate: myCellEditableTemplate},             
                    {field: 'last_login_date'},
                    {field: 'status'}
                    ];

            $scope.updateEntity = function (column, row) {
                // code for saving data to the server next...
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, according to [this documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Defining-columns) you can use the `enableCellEdit` column definition property to set only that column up for editing.  You may have to disable this property for the rest of your columns.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm ! I kept enableCellEditOnFocus: true in the gridOptions and added enableCellEdit: false in the coldefs for any column that needed to be readonly.