# Editable grid in AngularJs using ngGrid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have grid that will be partially editable. I mean there are 10 columns in my grid. Column number 2 to 6 will be editable rest of the column will be uneditable.

I need to implement a functionality where after editing the 6th column cell in a particular row the focus will shift to the next row 2 column. Rest of the column will not have focus.

Please help.
Thank you

Comment: Not a 100% match to your question, but you could set the last columns to readonly like was explained in this previous SO post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427707

Comment: Thanks AardVark. I did this so the rest of column are not in editable mode but still the focus goes on these cell. My requirement is to shift the focus directly to the desired column cell.